# Switch in javascript with boolean

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

Why is this code not working! It all the time goes to default no mater what I do and i did not see no one is having an issue similar to this in the stackoverflow. please help

```js
var age = 20;
switch(age){
 case(age<10):
 document.getElementById("box").innerHTML = "you are a kid";
 break;
 case(age>10 && age<=18 ):
  document.getElementById("box").innerHTML = "you are teen";
  break;
 
 case(age>18):
  document.getElementById("box").innerHTML = "you are adult";
  break;
  
 default:
  document.getElementById("box").innerHTML = "Some thing is broken!!";
  
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    
    
    </head>
<body>
   <div id="box"></div>
   
    <!--External Javascrip-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    </body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 11):

Switch out `age` for `true`. Do note that it's a lot more performant to use `if/else`:

```js
var age = 20;

switch (true) {
  case (age < 10):
    document.getElementById("box").innerHTML = "you are a kid";
    break;
  case (age > 10 && age <= 18):
    document.getElementById("box").innerHTML = "you are teen";
    break;

  case (age > 18):
    document.getElementById("box").innerHTML = "you are adult";
    break;

  default:
    document.getElementById("box").innerHTML = "Some thing is broken!!";
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```

Comment: Glad to help. Don't forget to mark this as correct.

Comment: I wasted so much time trying swtich(variable), I was like everything is correct with my conditions why it wouldn't go inside, and then I just put switch(true), and it all worked! Thanks.